# My Site For User Activity Alert

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i want to set alert on my site activities for user as daily/weekly/monthly basis.

for ex: collages recent activities

can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Comment: What kind of alert? Is it you want to notify a user about a recent activity? and I am not the person who has down voted you.

Comment: when the new colleagues add,edit or delete in my site colleagues list i want to send to email.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send email, look into Workflows... They are automated and can be set with logic and set for new / edited / created items.